# loading 3d index parameters from CSV files into python pyomo optimization model and debugging constraints

Tags: python, csv, debugging, pyomo

I'm having trouble debbuging my Abstract Model (it can't be Concrete) and i really don't understand why. I would really appreciate some help. I attach my github repo with the Jupyter Notebook and the sets and parameters as CSV files. https://github.com/juanraposo2000/PYOMO

I tried debbuging it several times, changing constraints and uploading csv files of parameters but it doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you'll get better/quicker responses if you post the code into the question in a minimally reproducible example instead of a link to some external site.

That said, you are closer than you think.  Your issue is in the syntax you used in your constraints.  You have this:

```
    #Upper thermal limit 
def Upper_Thermal_rule(model,t,n,s,p):
    return m.qt[t,n,s,p] <= m.u[t,n,s,p] * m.k[t] * m.qmax[t]
```

You should have this fix (in all of them):

```
    #Upper thermal limit 
def Upper_Thermal_rule(m,t,n,s,p):
    return m.qt[t,n,s,p] <= m.u[t,n,s,p] * m.k[t] * m.qmax[t]
```

Note that the first argument in the function is `m` instead of `model`.  You can actually use any/either/or something else, but it must be **consistent.**  Inside *your* function, `model` refers to your model, so when it gets to `m.qt[]` it barfs because `m` is not defined.

Do a find/replace in all of your constraints and make them consistent, and then you'll note that in several of the constraints you are not passing in the parameters (like `Upper_Hydro`).  Just read the errors closely and you'll get there.